# Executing the store procedure in MySQL Query Browser But not execute show exception like You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

**`Exception copied from MYSQL Query Browser`**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 10

```
**Store Procedure Code**

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_datafix_tp(       
p_appid INT, 
p_tpretail_prc decimal(18,5), 
p_tpcommission_amt decimal(18,5), 
check_ind char(1) )
Begin 

if check_ind='U'  

  Then 
   update application set tpretail_prc=p_tpretail_prc, tpcommission_amt =        p_tpcommission_amt where appid=p_appid;


  elseif check_ind='S'    
  Then

select appid,tpretail_prc,tpcommission_amt from application a
           where a.appid=p_appid; 

end if;

END;
```

- Looks Store Procedure Code is fine.
- I am using MySQL Server 5.5 version.
- I am using MySQL Query Browser 5.0 Version.

Comment: are you change delimiter for end of procedure? check manual's example. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DELIMITER $$ 
please add the above of the store procedure,

DELIMITER ;
and add this delimiter at the end of store procedure.

Comment: Why I will use delimiters in store procedure?

Answer (score 0):

No issue in Stored Procedure. I have run this SP on my local MySQL with version 5.6.

[image]

Comment: @Nwhaider please check the image I am using the MYSql Query Browser 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10

Comment: I think you are using Toad for mysql, it works on toad but not work on Query Browser.

Comment: DELIMITER $$
 CREATE PROCEDURE sp_datafix_tp(
 .
 .
 END IF;
   END $$
DELIMITER;

Comment: nwzhaider Why I will use the Delimiter on my store procedure?

Comment: please explain the usage of delimiter?

Comment: To run it without exception :p

Comment: If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.